# When can I hyphenate "in-place"?

Tags: conjunctions, hyphens

To me, these feel correct:

- They were replaced in-place.
- The dancers twirl in-place.
- Protections are in place.
- It shows squares in place of symbols.

But trying to look for information on its hyphenation, I only find examples of the word combination without a hyphen. (It's hard to find because most search engines, including Stackexchange's, ignores the hyphen and matches cases with a space.)

Are there cases where the hyphenated form is not correct (such as the unhyphenated examples above, where I felt a hyphen would be wrong)? Must some cases be hyphenated, or is it always correct (if potentially less clear?) to write it without hyphen?

Comment: The concept you're looking for is called a *phrasal adjective* (or more rarely other parts of speech).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Quick answer for general use:

**hyphenation is for adjectives, not adverbs:**

- They sheltered in place. [no hyphen]
- The dancers twirl in place. [no hyphen]
- The **in-place sheltering command** was given at dawn. [adjective]
- The boilers were replaced **on site**.
- **On-site replacement** of boilers is offered by the company. [adjective]

Comment: Your non-hyphenated cases are prepositional phrases.

Comment: @Barmar They sheltered in place. How did they shelter? How did they twirl. How did they repair the boilers? Also.

Comment: @Barmar Prepositional phrases can function as adverbs. More specifically, they are called adverbial phrases.