# Why is it "Server Side Include" instead of "Server-Side Include"?

Tags: adjectives, hyphens

Thanks to [Lambie](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/33113/lambie) I [recently learned](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/236898/31526) that compound adjectives are hyphenated, for example *[server-side request forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_request_forgery)*.

When looking up *server-side include(s)*, it appears that most places write this **without** a hyphen. To me, it seems that *server-side* modifies *include(s)*, functioning as an adjective. Someone even made a [redirect from *server-side* to *server side*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Server-side_include&redirect=no) on Wikipedia. Microsoft also speaks of [Server Side Include](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/serversideinclude). The [Indiana University](https://kb.iu.edu/d/bfsa) does the same.

What makes this situation different from *server-side request forgery*?

Comment: *Server Side* Management or *Client Side* Management are not adjectives, those are nouns.

Comment: *Server Side Include* is a feature, or as they say, a protocol. Those are names, hence nouns.

Comment: Your link to Free Dictionary site doesn't highlight its usage as Server-side, it is just redirected because you typed in that way. See this result, https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Server+side+include.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh Should *server-side request forgery* use a hyphen then? If not, then I don't understand when something is a compound adjective and when a compound noun. Could you elaborate on when it is which to help me understand? Also, please post answers as an answer :)

Comment: @Luc - compound adjectives **may** be hyphenated; they do not **have** to be.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Writing it separately might make the meaning unclear, though (based on [these examples on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound#Hyphenated_compound_modifiers)). I guess a "side include on the server" wouldn't make much sense and so a reader can surmise it must be "server-side include", but why not write clearly to begin with? And as far as I can tell, it is conventional to hyphenate compound adjectives if they're not an exception case (e.g. when including words like most/least, see the linked page).

Comment: The rule is more of a suggestion if needed for clarity or consistency.

Answer (score 5):

The hyphenated form is the one that is grammatically correct, but the hyphen is often omitted in casual contexts.

In the case of *SSI*, the form without the hyphen is simpler and cleaner, and these considerations may be more important than following the formal grammar. A hyphen would also create ambiguity about which letters to include in the abbreviated form (e.g. *SI* vs. *SSI*).

More, terms used in computer software (and hardware) often do not follow the standard features of language. They are as much marketing tools as descriptions of features, standards, or technologies.

For close analogy,  "random-access memory" and "read-only memory" are often given without hyphenation, and reference sources appear to vary on the recommendation. In either case, the middle term appearing in the initials, *RAM* versus *ROM*, is essential to express the distinction.

Comment: I'll add that especially in technical contexts, it's often important to use the exact phrasing used by other people or in documentation. "Server Side Include" without the hyphen has become jargon at this point. Clarity would not be improved by re-adding it.

Comment: @solublefish: The phrase originated not as jargon but as a choice for the name of a feature. The question is why the particular form of the name was chosen. That the name, once chosen, should be copied exactly is given.

Answer (score 1):

server-side x is an adjective and a noun.

For example:
1)
**Server-side scripting** is a technique used in web development which involves employing scripts on a web server which produce a response customised for each user's (client's) request to the website. The alternative is for the web server itself to deliver a static web page. Scripts can be written in any of a number of server-side scripting languages that are available (see below). Server-side scripting is distinguished from client-side scripting where embedded scripts, such as JavaScript, are run client-side in a web browser, but both techniques are often used together.**

[server-side scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting#:%7E:text=Server%2Dside%20scripting%20is%20a,deliver%20a%20static%20web%20page.)

2. TITLE:

> Introduction to the Server Side [used as noun, no dash, unusual but OK
> usage]
> **Welcome to the MDN beginner's **server-side programming** course! **
>
> Perhaps the most significant benefit of **server-side code** is that
> it allows you to tailor website content for individual users.

If you are just talking, and know what is being referred to, you can use server side with no noun or dash. If, however, a noun is used, it's best to use a dash.

[Server-side steps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Introduction)

server-side management and client-side management, follow the same rule.

These things are much clearer when a dash is used.

3. MICROSOFT

> **Server-side vs. client-only rules** Outlook for Microsoft 365 Outlook 2019 Outlook 2016 Outlook 2013 Rules are either server-side or
> client-only based on the conditions and actions you apply to them.
>
> Server-side rules use conditions and actions handled by the Exchange
> server, and these rules run whether or not you log in to Outlook on
> your computer. Here’s an example of a server-side rule:

[server-side versus client-only rules](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/server-side-vs-client-only-rules-e1847992-8aa1-4158-8e24-ad043decf1eb)

Summary: server-side x, client-side x are used as adjectives plus a noun.
In the Microsoft example, you can even see: client-only rules. Also, an adjective plus a noun. There are others but I don't have them all in my head.

This is exactly like: sugar-free drinks.

When you don't see a dash, it's because people do not know or are lazy.

Comment: Thanks again :) Could you comment on why it isn't a compound noun like [Dhanishtha Ghosh commented](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/262113/why-is-it-server-side-include-instead-of-server-side-include#comment491120_262113)? I'm wondering now if there is a good way to tell when something is a compound noun and when part of it is an adjective.

Comment: client side and server side are an adjective plus a noun: client=adjective, side=noun, for example. But when you use either one along with another term: server-side **programming**, *server side functions like an adjective* qualifying programming.